# Multikey index in Postgres

Tags: postgresql-performance, btree

I'm struggling to optimize on correct index creation for my data structure. I'm trying to index massive amount of data (~100B records) of json data type:

```json
{
  "email": "some@email.com",
  "first_domain": "q.w.e.r.t.y.com"
  "second_domain": "a.s.d.f.g.h.j.com"
}
```

Simple query might look like

```
SELECT * 
from table 
WHERE email = 'some@email.com'
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
from table 
WHERE first_domain LIKE '%.r.t.y.com'
   OR second_domain LIKE '%.r.t.y.com'
```

Previously I would tokenize all domains and put them together into an array in mongo

```json
{
  "values": ["some@email.com", "moc.y.t.r.e.w.q", moc.j.h.g.f.d.s.a]
}
```

But having amount I data Mongo can't store all values in memory and write performance degrades.

So I'm planning to give a try to Postgres and GIN index.
Please suggest me a proper index creation for such situation.

Comment: Why misuse JSON for this? If all JSON values are structured like that, it's much better to use a normal table with three columns.

Comment: I'm fine using normal tables and even reverse order of char to have right-hand side wildcard to avoid trigrams and have regular B-tree. The main issue I don't quite understand whether it is better to have 2 different indexes on domain fields or one for both. At any moment look up value can match only one or both of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query would be correctly written like this:

```
select *
from the_table
where the_json_column ->> 'email' = 'some@email.com'
```

That can be supported with a B-Tree index:

```
create index on the_table ((the_json_column ->> 'email'))
```

As the LIKE condition uses the wildcard on the left hand side, you'll need a [trigram](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) index (after installing the `pg_trgm` extension)

```
create index on the_table using gin ((the_json_column ->> 'first_domain') gin_trgm_ops);
create index on the_table using gin ((the_json_column ->> 'second_domain') gin_trgm_ops);
```

Again, you need to use the correct syntax to extract the values from the JSON column:

```
SELECT * 
from the_table 
WHERE the_json_column ->> 'first_domain' LIKE '%.r.t.y.com'
   OR the_json_column ->> 'second_domain' LIKE '%.r.t.y.com'
```